# Average test coverage only 13%. Need help on this @isTest Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

Trying to get a @isTest for this Apex Class.  apparently, I only have 13% Average test and need 75%.  Can you guys help?  Even just lead me the right way.

This is actually a convert button Proposal object to Listing object.

Getting a Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from String to Decimal at line 11 column 9.  Seems like any number for 2isTest gives me this error.  Any help will do.

```
public class ControllerProposalConvertView {
public Id pId;
public String convertedAccountId;

public ControllerProposalConvertView(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
    pId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    System.Debug('#######leadId:' + pId);
}


public PageReference convert(){

    try{
    Proposal__c p = [SELECT Id, name, Already_Converted__c, Property__c, Square_Footage__c, Lot_Size__c, Lot__c, Cap_Rate__c, Year_Built__c, Zoning__c, Term__c, Lease_Type__c, NOI__c, Lease_Commencement_Date__c, Rent_Commencement_Date__c, Lease_Expiration_Date__c, Years_Remaining__c, Lease_Notes__c FROM Proposal__c WHERE Id=:pId LIMIT 1];

    if (p.Already_Converted__c  =='Not Converted'){
    Listing__c c=new Listing__c(Name=p.Name, Property__c=p.Property__c, Square_Footage__c=p.Square_Footage__c,  Lot_Size__c=p.Lot_Size__c, Lot__c=p.Lot__c, Cap_Rate__c=p.Cap_Rate__c, Year_Built__c=p.Year_Built__c, Zoning__c=p.Zoning__c, Term__c=p.Term__c, Lease_Type__c=p.Lease_Type__c, NOI__c=p.NOI__c, Lease_Commencement_Date__c=p.Lease_Commencement_Date__c, Rent_Commencement_Date__c=p.Rent_Commencement_Date__c, Lease_Expiration_Date__c=p.Lease_Expiration_Date__c, Years_Remaining__c=p.Years_Remaining__c, Lease_Notes__c=p.Lease_Notes__c);
    System.Debug('#######c :' + c );
    insert c;
    p.Already_Converted__c='Converted';
   update p;
    convertedAccountId = c.Id;
    System.Debug('#######convertedAccountId :' + convertedAccountId );
    }

    else{
            String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
    sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + '/apex/ProposalConvertView2?id='+ pId); 
    retPage.setRedirect(true);
    System.Debug('#######ALREADYCONVERTED' );

    return retPage;
    }

    }

    catch(Exception e){
        System.Debug('#######Error  - Exception [' + e.getMessage() + ']');
        return null;
    }
    String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
    sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
    System.Debug('#######sServerName :' + sServerName );
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + convertedAccountId); 
    System.Debug('#######retPage :' + retPage );
    retPage.setRedirect(true);


    return retPage;
} 
public PageReference back(){
        String sServerName = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Host');
    sServerName = 'https://'+sServerName+'/';
    System.Debug('#######sServerName :' + sServerName );
    PageReference retPage = new PageReference(sServerName + pId); 
    System.Debug('#######retPage :' + retPage );
    retPage.setRedirect(true);

    return retPage;
}      
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class ControllerProposalConvertViewTest {

static testMethod void convert(){
    Listing__c c = new Listing__c ();
    c.Name = 'Test Name';
    c.Property__c = 'Test Property';
    c.Zoning__c = 'Zone';
    c.Lease_Type__c = 'Monthly';
    c.Lease_Notes__c = 'Ground Lease';
    c.Square_Footage__c = '50,000.00';
    c.Lot_Size__c = '10000';
    c.Lot__c = '50';
    c.Cap_Rate__c = '5.75';
    c.Year_Built__c = '1975';
    c.Term__c = '456';
    c.NOI__c = '123';
    c.Lease_Commencement_Date__c = '10/25/2015';
    c.Rent_Commencement_Date__c = '10/26/2015';
    c.Lease_Expiration_Date__c = '10/27/2015';
    c.Years_Remaining__c = '10';
    insert c;

    }
}
```

Comment: update this question with your test class code as well. including the screenshot of covered portion.

Comment: What are you actually having trouble with?  The concept of test methods? Or are there particular scenarios that you're having trouble testing?  There are a lot of resources out there that cover testing.

Comment: I guess creating a @isTest so I can increase it to 75% test coverage.

Comment: Have a read of:  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods   That should get you started, so give it a shot and if there's any specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks @NickCook you're awesome.  I just did my fist few lines and no error so far...  Ill keep you posted

isTest
public class ControllerProposalConvertViewTest {
    
    static testMethod void convert(){
        Listing__c c = new Listing__c ();
        
    }
}

Comment: @NickCook I made some updates so i'm just getting a new error.  Any advice?

Comment: @NinjaKing. You need to assign values to the field based on their type. If it is string then assign string value. If it is a number type then assign numeric values. looks like `Square_Footage__c  , Lot_Size__c and c.Lot__c` are the numeric type. pass numeric type ex: `Square_Footage__c = 50,000.00 ` remove '' single quotes. Single quotes means it is a string type.

Comment: @ratan what if it is a date?         

c.Lease_Commencement_Date__c = 10/25/2015;
c.Rent_Commencement_Date__c = 10/26/2015;
c.Lease_Expiration_Date__c = 10/27/2015;  I cant use quotes and even removing quotes doesnt work.

Comment: for date your need to use date method like `date.Today()`. Read documentation lots of methods present https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm

Comment: Which object is the standard controller in your VF page?

Comment: @SantanuHalder there's one for Proposal, Listing, and Escrow.  But this one is in Proposal.  Any Advice

Comment: Wrote my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I dont want to write the whole test class for you. However I can give you steps you need to do in your test class.
In your test method `static testMethod void convert()`

1. First create a `Proposal__c` record with all the mandatory fields. Set `Already_Converted__c  = 'Not Converted'`. After creation,lets say your proposal record is p.
2. First set your test page to the VF page from where you are pressing Convert button. like this -

   ```
   PageReference pageRef = Page.YourVfPageName;
   Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
   ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',p.Id);//p is the Proposal record you inserted in first step.
   ApexPages.StandardController std = new ApexPages.StandardController(new Proposal__c());//Assuming the standard controller is Proposal for your VF page.
   ControllerProposalConvertView cont = new ControllerProposalConvertView(std);
   cont.convert();
   ```
3. Then write another test method with exact same code, but this time set the `Already_Converted__c` field value to something else other than 'Not Converted'.

Comment: so is my test method in the beginning wrong?  Should I delete that?

Comment: Yes, its not helping you in anyway. Keep it commented as of now.

Comment: ok let me try it and i'll repost

Comment: When you say P is that the record name?  I'm lost on that

Comment: This is what I wrote so far and stuck on P.  Sorry just a little confused

`@isTest
public class ControllerProposalConvertViewTest2 {
    
    static testMethod void convert(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.ProposalConvertView;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',p.Id);
        ControllerProposalConvertView cont = new ControllerProposalConvertView(new Proposal__c());
        cont.convert();
        
    }
}`

Comment: You didnt created the record P as I mentioned in the point #1. Create a variable p of type Proposal__c with all mandatory fields. Like this - `Proposal p = new Proposal(Name='Test Prop', Already_Converted__c  = 'Not Converted');` Provide all mandatory field values like I have given for `name` & `Already_Converted__c`. And then `insert p`.

Comment: I did this...
        `Proposal p = new Proposal (p.Name = 'Test Name', p.Already_Converted__c = 'Not Converted',p.Property__c = 'a007A000001C6CM', p.Zoning__c = 'Zone',p.Lease_Type__c = 'Monthly', p.Lease_Notes__c = 'Ground Lease',p.Lot_Size__c = 100.00,p.Lot__c = 50.00,p.Cap_Rate__c = 512.75,p.Year_Built__c = '1975',p.Term__c = 456,p.NOI__c = 123.12,p.Years_Remaining__c = 10.50,p.Lease_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Rent_Commencement_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Lease_Expiration_Date__c = date.Today(),p.Square_Footage__c = 50000),`

Comment: i didnt get any error that but now im getting a Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'pageRef' at line 6 column 22


        `PageReference pageRef = Page.ProposalConvertView; 
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',p.Id); 
        ControllerProposalConvertView cont = new ControllerProposalConvertView (new Proposal__c()); 
        cont.convert();`

Any advice??

Comment: p.Square_Footage__c = 50000) end this line with a ; not ,

Comment: Plus since you are hardcoding ID in your test class, please annotate your test class to seeAllData= true like this at the top of the class. @IsTest(SeeAllData=true). Although its not a good practice.

Comment: I got all that squared away.  I'm just getting Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [ControllerProposalConvertView].<Constructor>(Proposal__c) at line 9 column 46 `ControllerProposalConvertView cont = new ControllerProposalConvertView (new Proposal__c()); `

Comment: Oh I am sorry, thats my fault. I have updated my code in mu answer. Forgot to create a StandardController instance and then pass it to extension controller

Comment: ControllerProposalConvertView (std);  - it says variable does not exist

Comment: I am sure you didn't copied the line above that ControllerProposalConvertView line. hehe!

Comment: im such an idiot.  ahhh sucks only 24% coverage.  I still have to do another test right? which is CONVERTED?

Comment: Ya write another test method with same code but Already_Converted__c field value to something else other than 'Not Converted'. And then call the back() function as well from that test method at last.

Comment: haha you lost me at back() function.   Kindly explain please.  So I will create another record in Proposal__c and name 'Converted' in Already_Converted__c.  I will write another question on why its only on 24% thanks for your help.  Ireally truly appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32098/discussion-between-santanu-halder-and-ninja-king).